# Issue With Trying to Import a Local File in Node v14.15.1

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to import a local file from my project's directory to my server.js. The directory structure is like this:

```
server
  node_modules
  server.js (error occurs here) 
  src
    models
    api
       controllers
       routes
         posts.js (trying to import this file, edited to show actual filename)
```

Here's the error it throws

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                          ^

 Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\ReactProjects\memoirs\server\src\api\routes\posts' 
 imported from E:\ReactProjects\memoirs\server\server.js
 Did you mean to import ../src/api/routes/posts.js?
  at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:276:11)
  at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
  at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
  at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
  at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
  at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

and my server.js file:

```
import express from 'express';
import posts from './src/api/routes/posts'; // is there a problem with this file path?

const app = express();

app.use('/api/v1/posts', posts); // error seems to be here, server works if commented out

app.listen(3004, (err)=>{
if(err){
    console.log(err);
}
console.log('server at port 3004');
});
```

The issue seems to be with the file path. I have tried re-arranging it but for some weird reason can't load that particular file into server.js Is there any clear explanation for why this is happening and how to rectify it? Thanks.

Comment: My bad, the filename is actually posts. Editing the question now. Thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you made a typo. You wrote `posts` instead of `post`.

```js
import post from './src/api/routes/post';
```

EDIT: Seeing that this was just a typo in the question, here is something you could try t fix it:

I would rely on [CommonJS Require](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) rather than [ES6 Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) on this one, because you can specify relative paths easily by utilizing [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname):

```
let express = require('express');
let posts = require(__dirname + '/src/api/routes/posts.js');
```

Comment: EDIT:  Please check again, that was a mistake while asking the question. Actual filename and import are same as posts. Thank you sir

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that. It worked. Any reason why I had to use __dirname even though it's commonjs? I thought the issue was cos I tried using ES6

Comment: @Nzadibe Thats hard to tell without being able to traverse your actual project structure. I suggested using `__dirname` just to be extra safe. You can try to just write `require('./src/api/routes/posts.js');` and see if it works for you

Comment: Alright, my project structure is described above, accurately. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've finally solved this! I got clue from react which throws exact error on not writing `.js` while importing. You must write extension of even a .js file for node 14+ if you are using `type: 'module'` in package.json.

Check this image
[image: Check this image]

**Solution**

- So the solution is edit the second line of `server.js`,
  from
- `import posts from './src/api/routes/posts'`
  to
- `import posts from './src/api/routes/posts.js'`